# Textbox with password properties in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, passwords, hide

In Netbeans, is it possible to hide the type password in a textbox with asterisk (`******`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean that you need to design a Swing UI with a password text field you should simply use the JPasswordField component form the standard Swing palette.

Answer (score 1):

Use JPasswordField